# ng-show not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oop, ionic-framework

The code I have tried is :

html code(updata.html)

```
<form role="form" ng-submit="submit()">
<input type="text" ng-model="query" >
      <div class="item item-input item-stacked-label item-divider">
      <li ng-repeat="name in names | filter:query" ng-show="(!name.selected&&query)">
      <button type="button" ng-click="name.selected=true; addname(name)">{{name.name}}</button>
    </li>

      </div>
      <li ng-repeat="name in names" ng-show="name.selected">{{name.name}}</li>
 <div class="padding">
      <button type="submit" class="button button-block button-positive">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

angular js code

```
 angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova','ngRoute'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
 $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
// Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the   accessory bar above the keyboard
// for form inputs)
if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
}
if(window.StatusBar) {
  StatusBar.styleDefault();
}
});
})
.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider.when(
 '/',{
  templateUrl: 'main.html',
  controller: 'datactr'
}
)
.when(
'/indata',{
  templateUrl:'updata.html',
  controller:'datactr'
})
.when(
'/outdata',{
  templateUrl:'outdata.html',
  controller:'datactr'
})
.otherwise({
redirectTo:'/'
})
}])
.controller('datactr',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http) {
$scope.submit=function(){
          console.log("step1");

    $http({
      method:'POST',
      url:'http://awesomeg.2fh.co/updata.php',
      crossDomain : true,
      data:{
         'name':$scope.namefinal
          }
      }).success(function(data,status,header,config){
      console.log("step2");
      console.log(data);
      $scope.namefinal="";
      $scope.message="You have successfully updated the database";
    })
    $scope.names=[{'name' :'harry',
'selected':false},{'name' :'george',
'selected':false}];
$scope.namefinal=[];
$scope.addname=function(test){
$scope.namefinal.push(test.name);
}     
}])
```

This is part of my ionic code.Names is an array of objects with property name and selected.so when a user types in a name it gives suggesstions.when you click suggestions the selected property of object is changed to true.What is expected then is to see a list of selected object name at the bottom but it does not show.

Can anyone help?

Comment: There is an typo i.e. !name.setected&&query in your HTML. Make sure you have selected instead of setected

Comment: the question is not about that part it works quite fine.The question is about the bottom part <li ng-repeat="name in names" ng-show="name.selected">{{name.name}}</li> it does not show anything.

Comment: if this was the logic it would work. it's all about typos i guess. for example you have {{symptom.name}} there. if it shows any text in browser there then your li element has ng-repeat="symtpom in names" or something. just check your spellings and flow, you'll find.

Comment: the thing is i change the variable name when i post the question here so that is where typos have arrived.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is a spelling mistake

```
<li ng-repeat="name in names | filter:query" ng-show="(!name.setected&&query)">
```

it should be `ng-show="(!name.selected&&query)"`

Comment: changed it but have the same problem.The question is not about that part it works quite fine.The question is about the bottom part <li ng-repeat="name in names" ng-show="name.selected">{{name.name}}</li> it does not show anything.

Comment: @SGiritheja Is there any other code which might be affecting this functionality? The code appears to be fine.

Comment: @K K i don't think so.Anyway i have edited to include my full code .